# What is Difference Between AND,OR operator in MYSQL ,While Retrieving the Rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, logical-operators

Are there difference between these queries and how they execute?

```
SELECT   customername, country, creditLimit
FROM   customers
WHERE (country = 'USA' OR country = 'France') AND creditlimit > 100000;
```

```
SELECT    customername, country, creditLimit
FROM    customers
WHERE country = 'USA' OR country = 'France' AND creditlimit > 10000;
```

Comment: The AND operator is used to validate multiple conditionals in your query, the OR is for the query to only validate one of the conditionals depending on the data. 

In the above queries you would get pretty much the same results in function of the credlimit of course.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_operators.asp

You can learn a lot about SQL operators in that page.

Comment: Actually the result of this would be that if the country is USA the creditlimit would be ignored.

Comment: It has to with the order of operation and is analogous to the PEMDAS rule. This is why it's considered a good practice to use parenthesis even if it doesn't change the output. It's not just for getting the right result, but also for communicating the intent of the conditionals for documentation purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's to do with intersecting truth tables.

In the first query the or is inside brackets so it will execute first and return true if the country is either USA or France.  Then the And will execute and compare the result of the OR to the result of creditlimit > 100000.

In the second query operator precedence takes over, so whether the Or or the And is executed first.  According to this site https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-or/

> Operator precedence
>   When you use more than one logical operator in an expression, MySQL always evaluates the OR operators after the AND operators. This is called operator precedence which determines the order of evaluation of the operators. MySQL evaluates the operator with higher precedence first.

This means that in this query the database will check to see if the Country is France and the creditlimit > 10000 before then running the OR statement between the result and whether the country is USA.

ETA: in plain english the second query, will return all results where the country is USA regardless of the credit limit, it will also return any results where the country is france and the credit limit > 10000.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue you are going to run into with your queries is the order of operations.  Please check out the following article on operator precedence ([Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html))

Since AND has a higher precedence, your second query is interpreted as follows:

```sql
SELECT customername, country, creditLimit FROM customers WHERE country = 'USA' OR (country = 'France' AND creditlimit > 10000);
```

So the second query only looks for the country being USA or the country being France and credit limit > 10,000.